# How to make a Sharepoint drop-down list in read only

Tags: sharepoint-designer, dropdown

I'm new with Sharepoint. I have a form and I edit it with Sharepoint designer. I would like to disable a drop-down list (I want just show the value without the possibility to change it). I don't know exactly how to do that directly in the code of the Sharepoint field?

Here my field:

```
    <tr class="UniqueKeyMasterContract">
        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                <nobr>UniqueKey</nobr>
            </H3>
        </td>
        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="UniqueKeyMasterContract" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@UniqueKeyMasterContract')}"/>
            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff1description{$Pos}" FieldName="UniqueKeyMasterContract" ControlMode="New"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Could you please help me with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to render the field as "Display". You can do this by setting the control mode to display, here is an example:

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="TitleField" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Title" />
```

I would recommend taking backups of your custom form when editing with SharePoint Designer. I have found if SP Designer finds a mistake during the post save validation, it tends to delete everything in your form.